# How to find the relative location of a 3d point on a surface transformed in 3d space

Tags: matrix, 3d, raycasting

I have a math/vector/matrix question that I can't seem to work out.

I have 4 points in 3D space that represent the bounds of a surface.

I have written a raycast algoritum to get the intersection location of the mouse "ray" against the rectangle in the 3d scene.

The rectangle in the scene has a rotation and translation matrix applied to it so it can be moved anywhere in the scene, and my raycast system does correctly get the ray hit location on the surface.

My problem is that I need to now take the Ray Hit location that is in world space and work out where on the 2d surface of the rectangle the hit is.

I cannot work out how to do this.

Comment: You are using a mixed language geometry/math/something-I-dont-get which I, personally, cannot understand properly. Please, clarify what you are looking for and provide the right inputs if you want to get help quickly. If you want to focus the problem/solution as geometrical/mathematical one, post the expected inputs/outputs, and the pseudo-algorithm for the calculations; you can rely on C# and just write down this information (inputs/outputs, calcs). If you prefer your specific code to be fixed, post it (again, together with the expected inputs/outputs). Please, help us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hit point is in the world space. To get the point in the same coordinate system as the original 4 points, just calculate the inverse of the rotation and translation matrix and multiply this inverse matrix by the hit point.

The resulting point will be in the same coordinate system as the 4 points that represent the bounds of the surface.

Comment: I will give this a go, I think I can calculate a inverse matrix.

Thanks!

Comment: "In the world space"? Are you (and the OP) referring to a specific type of implementation (in gaming or something like that)? And could you please make all this (question and answer) understandable for anyone who expects math talking in a math-tagged question?

Comment: Yep that worked, I tried creating the matrix in reverse but I hadn't tried using an inverse matrix of the transform to get into the object space.

Thanks, Marked as answer.

Comment: @DanielArmstrong do you understand that this is not between you and a specific answerer talking a language only you both seem to understand? Also do you know that it is pretty unpolite not answering someone talking to you (who, on top of that, is intending to help)? If you don't mind, I will remove some tags because they don't reflect clearly what is going on here (I can also add the "private-chat" one :))

Comment: @varocarbas with world space I mean that the hit point is in another coordinate system different of that of the 4 pints defining the rectangle. This is because the rectangle has been applied a transformation (rotation/translation) and the hit point has been calculated in this new coordinate system. As we want the hit point referenced in the same system as the original 4 points, what we have to do is to reverse the transformation just by multiplying by the inverse matrix.

Comment: I (kind of) got that. My question was related to the "world space" expression I haven't ever heard about. The question and your answer didn't refer to a properly-defined 3D-geometry problem; even though you both seemed to understand perfectly each other, that's why I assumed that all this was referred to some kind of standard methodology (for example, for game development). If you were referring to two different reference systems, you should say so: ref-system-1 (call it "world" if you like it, but make the point clear) and ref-system-2.

Comment: World space is a common expression in game development and other 3d rendering scenes. In game development if you draw a 3d model you apply a world matrix transform to the vertices in the vertex shader. He suggested to invert the world matrix I used to render my plane to get back from world space into local or (object) space. I was unaware that there was any other term used to describe this, I thought world space and object space were it. Is there anything else you wanted to know?